# Joomla Wrapper with auto height to display the content without frame's scrollbar

Tags: joomla, embed, iframe, automation

Is it possible to display the content of other website in my Joomla page (using the "Wrapper" menu item type) with autodetection of its height?

I don't know the exact height of the embedded dynamic page in pixels, but I want to display it without vertical scrollbar inside of my frame.

Joomla 1.5.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few month ago. To display the content of a site on same domain is no problem, but display the content from another domain was a bit tricky.

What me helped a lot, for both variants, was an article from Chris Coyier about [cross domain resizing](http://css-tricks.com/5210-cross-domain-iframe-resizing/).